# Bundle.loadClass() returns Class instance without fields or methods

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, equinox, apache-felix

I want to create an OSGi framework programmatically, load a Bundle with it and load a class from that bundle. When I call `Bundle.loadClass()` I get a `Class` isntance with all fields\methods\constructor fields set to null. It only has a name. I can't access any public methods, etc. I have tried both Equinox and Felix with the same result.

Bundle's `MANIFEST`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: org.osgitest.osgitest.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-Name: OSGi Test
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.osgitest.osgitest
Bundle-Version: 1.0
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
Export-Package: org.osgitest.osgitest.test
```

Framework setup:

```
FrameworkFactory ff = new EquinoxFactory();
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
config.put("org.osgi.framework.storage.clean", "onFirstInit");
Framework framework = ff.newFramework(config);
framework.init();
framework.start();
```

and

```
FrameworkFactory ff = new org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory();
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
config.put("org.osgi.framework.storage.clean", "onFirstInit");
Framework framework = ff.newFramework(config);
framework.init();
framework.start();
```

Bundle loading:

```
Bundle testBundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle("file:C:\\org-osgitest-osgitest.jar");
testBundle.start();
Class<?> classOne = testBundle.loadClass("org.osgitest.osgitest.test.ClassOne");
Class<?> activator = testBundle.loadClass("org.osgitest.osgitest.Activator");
```

Activator `Class` instance contains constructor reference, but no public methods. It has `public void start(BundleContext c)` and `public void stop(BundleContext c)`.

How can I load the correct `Class`? What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class` uses some kind of lazy-initialization. `Class` instance will be filled with methods/fields only after execution of `getMethods` etc. This is why I was not able to see anything in the debugger.

I tried to invoke `public static void main(String[] args)` and did not cast my `String[]` to `Object`. So it was interpreted like `Object[]` and JVM looked for a method with signature `(args[0].class, args[1].class, ... , args[n].class)`. This is why my method was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Since a bundle is a jar, have you tried to load the class in normal -classpath mode? OSGi just defines classloaders. The VM is still responsible for creating the Class objects from the bytecodes. So I don't see how an OSGi framework could "strip" the members from the Class object.